# Standard way to maintain socket listeners

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have an node.js socket.io application where I have a few different events and listeners. Right now this is how I am doing it.

```
class testEmitterClass extends events {
}

const testEmitter = new testEmitterClass();

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log('connected');

    let dnsInactiveTermsListener = function (dnsInactiveTerms) {
        socket.emit(socketEvents.DNS_INACTIVE_TERMS, dnsInactiveTerms);
    };

    let checkpointInactiveTermsListener = function(checkpointInactiveTerms) {
        socket.emit(socketEvents.CHECKPOINT_INACTIVE_TERMS, checkpointInactiveTerms);
    };

    let dnsActiveTermsListener = function (dnsActiveTerms) {
        socket.emit(socketEvents.DNS_ACTIVE_TERMS, dnsActiveTerms);
    };

    let checkpointActiveTermsListener = function(checkpointActiveTerms) {
        socket.emit(socketEvents.CHECKPOINT_ACTIVE_TERMS, checkpointActiveTerms);
    };

    let dnsCountListener = function (dnsCountStreaming) {
        socket.emit(socketEvents.DNS_COUNT, dnsCountStreaming);
    };

    testEmitter.on(socketEvents.CHECKPOINT_ACTIVE_TERMS, checkpointActiveTermsListener);
    testEmitter.on(socketEvents.DNS_INACTIVE_TERMS, dnsInactiveTermsListener);
    testEmitter.on(socketEvents.CHECKPOINT_INACTIVE_TERMS, checkpointInactiveTermsListener);
    testEmitter.on(socketEvents.DNS_ACTIVE_TERMS, dnsActiveTermsListener);
    testEmitter.on(socketEvents.DNS_COUNT, dnsCountListener);

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {

        console.log('disconnected');

        testEmitter.removeListener(socketEvents.DNS_INACTIVE_TERMS, dnsInactiveTermsListener);
        testEmitter.removeListener(socketEvents.DNS_ACTIVE_TERMS, dnsActiveTermsListener);
        testEmitter.removeListener(socketEvents.DNS_COUNT, dnsCountListener);
        testEmitter.removeListener(socketEvents.CHECKPOINT_INACTIVE_TERMS, checkpointInactiveTermsListener);
        testEmitter.removeListener(socketEvents.CHECKPOINT_ACTIVE_TERMS, checkpointActiveTermsListener);

    })

});
```

The testemitter is a single instance which is emitting events somewhere else and being sent to the client using socket.io

Is there a way to maintain single list of the listeners somewhere so that this code can be maintained better? How can I map events to the listeners so that they can be added and removed as a client disconnected from socket.io without making a mess.

socketEvents is just an object of event names.

```
const DNS_COUNT = 'dnsCount';
const DNS_INACTIVE_TERMS = 'dnsInactiveTerms';
const DNS_ACTIVE_TERMS = 'dnsActiveTerms';
const CHECKPOINT_INACTIVE_TERMS = 'checkpointInactiveTerms';
const CHECKPOINT_ACTIVE_TERMS = 'checkpointActiveTerms';

module.exports = {
    DNS_COUNT,
    DNS_INACTIVE_TERMS,
    CHECKPOINT_INACTIVE_TERMS,
    DNS_ACTIVE_TERMS,
    CHECKPOINT_ACTIVE_TERMS
};
```

Hope I made myself clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can change the whole way you do things.  Rather than register an event handler for every single socket that connects, you can just broadcast the message to all connected sockets.  So, I think you can replace everything you show with just this:

```
class testEmitterClass extends events {
}

const testEmitter = new testEmitterClass();

const notifications = [
    CHECKPOINT_ACTIVE_TERMS,
    DNS_INACTIVE_TERMS,
    CHECKPOINT_INACTIVE_TERMS,
    CHECKPOINT_INACTIVE_TERMS,
    DNS_COUNT
];

for (let msg of notifications) {
    testEmitter.on(socketEvents[msg], function(data) {
        // send this message and data to all currently connected sockets
        io.emit(socketEvents[msg], data);
    });
}
```

Also notice that the code has been [DRYed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) by using a table of messages that you can loop through rather than repeating the same statements over and over again.  So, now to add, remove or edit one of your notification messages, you just modify the table in one place.

---

If `socketEvents` (which you don't show) is just an object with these 5 properties on it, then you could even remove the `notifications` array by just iterating the properties of `socketEvents`.

That would further reduce the code to this:

```
class testEmitterClass extends events {
}

const testEmitter = new testEmitterClass();

for (let msg of Object.keys(socketEvents)) {
    testEmitter.on(socketEvents[msg], function(data) {
        // send this message and data to all currently connected sockets
        io.emit(socketEvents[msg], data);
    });
}
```

Comment: This works, meaning I can get the events across to the client. I just had one doubt, whenever the client disconnects, the listener is not removed from the emitter. If I do console.log(testEmitter.listenerCount('dnsActiveTerms')); It always increases on new client connecting but never decreases on them disconnecting. Is there a way to make that happen? That was why I initially binded each listener to a function.

Comment: @SalmaanP - You must be doing something different than I intended.  I show NO code at all inside the `connect` event.  This code is outside of all that.  The result of `console.log(testEmitter.listenerCount('dnsActiveTerms'));` should be `1` no matter how many sockets you have connected.  The idea is that you use `io.emit()` to broadcast to all connected sockets whenever you get an event.  You don't make listeners on each connected socket, therefore you don't have to undo them when they disconnect. You make one set of listeners on `testEmitter()` and send those events to all connected sockets.

Comment: understood, thanks a lot for the detailed reply and being patient with me :)